# Caliburn Micro App Bootstrapper is not called

Tags: caliburn.micro

I am trying to create a simple WPF application. However, I am keeping the views, models and bootstrapper in separate class library and calling it from a separate WPF application.

My library has just one view for main window, one MainWindow xaml class and a Bootstrapper derived class. Currently I have overloaded `OnStartup`

Here is my OnStartup code

```
protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
{
    return base.GetInstance(serviceType, key);
}
```

Here is my WPF App.Xaml is calling it

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <my:AppBootStrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Problem is, I noticed that Bootstrapper object is created but `OnStartup` is never called. Why ?

Do I have to do anything extra ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize() is required in the Bootstrap Constructor

Comment: just checked the samples all have it in the source on GitHub for WPF type application.  Now the Universal Apps are slightly different